# Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification failed

Tags: jenkins, ssh, ansible, centos, ssh-keys

I am facing an issue while executing the ansible-playbook form Jenkins,

like :

```
PLAY [centos-slave-02] *********************************************************



TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************

fatal: [centos-slave-02]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Host key verification failed.", "unreachable": true}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************

centos-slave-02            : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

but I am able to get ping-pong response and each time its asking for

```
Matching host key in /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:5  :
```

```
jenkins@c11582cb5024:~/jenkins-ansible$ ansible -i hosts -m ping centos-slave-02

Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'centos-slave-02' differs from the key for the IP address '172.19.0.3'

Offending key for IP in /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:2

Matching host key in /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:5

Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

---

```
centos-slave-02 | SUCCESS => {

    "ansible_facts": {

        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"

    },

    "changed": false,

    "ping": "pong"

}
```

could anyone  please fix this issue!thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `known_hosts` file in the `jenkins-ansible` host already has an entry for the host `centos-slave-02`. Now that the `centos-slave-02` host's identity has changed, a new entry needs to be added. But the existing entry in the file is throwing this warning.

> ```
> Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'centos-slave-02' differs from the key for the IP address '172.19.0.3'
>
> Offending key for IP in /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:2
>
> Matching host key in /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts:5
> ```

You can either manually edit the `/var/jenkins_home/.ssh/known_hosts` file to remove the key for this `centos-slave-02` host or run the below command,

```
ssh-keygen -R centos-slave-02
```

The workaround with ansible would be to add this line in `ansible.cfg` under `[defaults]` section,

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

This will disable `HostKeyChecking` when making SSH connections.

Comment: Keep in mind that disabling HostKeyChecking is really bad practice. The most correct thing to do would be to set up SSH User/Host Certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't use sudo in your jenkin build Exec command.